# In Taurus, how to pass ${TAURUS_ARTIFACTS_DIR} to JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, taurus

In my yaml, I have followed this doc:

- http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/

And have set:

```
 modules:
  jmeter:
    properties:
      myoutputdir: ${TAURUS_ARTIFACTS_DIR}/output
```

And then I’d like to use it using __P function, but it is not passed.
If I pass another static value it works.

Is it a bug or I need to escape something ?

**EDIT :**

**- I don't know what I was doing wrong, but the same code now works. So this question is stupid but I cannot delete it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue using [latest Taurus 1.12.1](https://github.com/Blazemeter/taurus/releases/tag/1.12.1)

- YAML config file used:

  ```
  modules:
    jmeter:
      properties:
        myoutputdir: ${TAURUS_ARTIFACTS_DIR}/output
  execution:
  - scenario: simple
  scenarios:
    simple:
      script: test.jmx
  ```
- Property referenced in [JSR223 Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) as `${__P(myoutputdir,)}` and printed to [STDOUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)) as `println('-----MYOUTPUTDIR='  +args[0])`

I can see current Taurus output directory printed to *jmeter.out* file under the artifacts directory:

[image: JMeter Taurus Property]

So try [upgrading to latest Taurus version](http://gettaurus.org/install/Installation/#Upgrading-Taurus) and double-checking your YAML config file

Comment: Strange, I am using this version. Does it work if you use property in SimpleDataWriter with __P function ?

Comment: Well, I tested again, and its working so I don't know what I was missing. Thanks again for your answer anyway. I accepted it.